# How to extract column headers (variables names) of data frames and store them as variable in a different data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I have three data frames with a different number of columns and observations. I would like to create a new data frame which lists all of the different variables from each data frame and specify the file name.

**I have three data frames:**

```
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)

a<-tibble(
 z=c(1,2,3),
 y=c(4,5,6),

)

b<-tibble(
  n=c(1,2),
  q=c(4,5),
  r=c(3,6),
)

c<-tibble(
  l=c(1,2),
  e=c(4,5),
  d=c(3,6),
)
```

**I can easily extract the column names for one data frame and also specify which file it came from.**

```
df<-as.data.frame(names(a))%>%
  dplyr::mutate(sheet=deparse(substitute(a)))
```

**How do I iterate this over multiple data frames and save out a data frame as shown below:**

```
df<-tibble::tibble(
  name=c("z", "y", "n", "q", "r", "l", "e", "d"),
  sheet=c("a", "a","b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")
)

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>  name  sheet
#>   z     a    
#>   y     a    
#>   n     b    
#>   q     b    
#>   r     b    
#>   l     c
```

I would like to do this using purrr but I am still in the learning stage. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option is to placee it in `list`, extract the `names`, `enframe` to a two column `data.frame`, and `unnest` the 'value' column

```
library(tidyverse)
lst(a, b, c) %>% 
    map(names) %>%
    enframe %>% 
    unnest
```

If we need a `class` column as well

```
lst(a, b, c) %>%
       map_dfr(~ tibble(name = names(.x), Class = map_chr(.x, class)), 
          .id = 'grp')
```

---

In `base R`

```
stack(lapply(mget(c('a', 'b', 'c')), names))[2:1]
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! It worked. Just one follow-up question: Would it be possible to also include the class of the variables as an additional column?

Comment: @brin  Is it a string column or `list` column

Comment: @brin try `lst(a, b, c) %>% 
     map_dfr(~ tibble(name = names(.x), Class = map_chr(.x, class)), .id = 'grp')`

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I really appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

It would be much easier if you had all your objects in a list, but here's a function that can take a list of variables and return the list you are after

```
get_cols <- function(...) {
  vars <- rlang::enquos(...)
  purrr::map_dfr(vars, ~tibble(sheet=rlang::as_name(.x), name=names(rlang::eval_tidy(.x))))

}

get_cols(a, b, c)
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#   sheet name 
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 a     z    
# 2 a     y    
# 3 b     n    
# 4 b     q    
# 5 b     r    
# 6 c     l    
# 7 c     e    
# 8 c     d
```

Comment: Getting the following Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects: * Column `name` is NULL Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: @brin I just tested in a new R session and it worked for me. I've got `rlang_0.3.1` and `purrr_0.3.0`. Is it possible you have different versions of those package?

Comment: thanks for your help!! I have the most recent versions for both packages. Not sure why it is not working. The above solution worked, so going with that!